# Image overlay over the TextureView android

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview, android-camera2, android-textureview

I want to overlay some image over the textureView(Camera preview) and there is one constraint that the image height should be equal to image width. Which means the image width height will change depending upon the screen sizes keeping the aspect ratio constant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/view_finder"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/stencil"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/stencil"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/stencil"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/stencil"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:id="@+id/stencil"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:src="@drawable/group"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               tools:ignore="ContentDescription,MissingConstraints"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/capture_button"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the textureview is dependent on the imageview size. As the imageview changes so well the textureview. I am calculating the textureview size programmatically.

```
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also 
 {view_finder.display.getMetrics(it)}
        val aspectRatio = Rational(viewFinder.width, viewFinder.height)
        val rotation = view_finder.display.rotation
        val resolution = Size(viewFinder.width, viewFinder.height)

        val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
            setTargetResolution(resolution)
        }.build()
```

But getting this error - CorrectedAspectRatio- some issue with aspect ratio

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get camera ID for use 
    case androidx.camera.core.Preview-c05d3e16-8833-42f4-ac22-4783402891dc
            at 
 androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getCameraIdFromConfig(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:310)
            at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.requiresCorrectedAspectRatio(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:268)
```

Comment: Any guidance in this regard is extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do the same with a little different approach and it worked like a charm. The overlayed image is only for reference. [image]This activity returns the path of the clicked photo without the overlayed image. Front and back camera both working in this activity.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.aranoah.healthkart.plus.R;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

import static android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class CameraStencilActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @BindView(R.id.textture)
    TextureView textture;
    @BindView(R.id.stencil)
    ImageView stencil;
    @BindView(R.id.stencil_description)
    TextView stencilDescription;

    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private StencilItem stencilItem;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    public static final int STENCIL_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    public static final String KEY_CAPTURED_STENCIL_DATA = "KEY_CAPTURED_STENCIL_DATA";
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private Integer mCameraLensFacingDirection;

    public static void startForResult(Fragment fragment, StencilItem stencilItem)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(fragment.getContext(), CameraStencilActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("stencil", stencilItem);
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, STENCIL_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_rotate)
    void onRotateClick()
    {
        switchCamera();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_stencil);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        stencilItem = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("stencil");
        Glide.with(this).load(stencilItem.getStencil().getUrl()).into(stencil);
        textture.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        stencilDescription.setText(stencilItem.getStencil().getUnderlineText());
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void switchCamera()
    {
        if (mCameraLensFacingDirection == LENS_FACING_BACK)
        {
            mCameraLensFacingDirection = CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
            closeCamera();
            reopenCamera();

        } else if (mCameraLensFacingDirection == CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            mCameraLensFacingDirection = LENS_FACING_BACK;
            closeCamera();
            reopenCamera();
        }
    }

    private void reopenCamera()
    {
        if (textture.isAvailable())
        {
            openCamera();
        } else
        {
            textture.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback()
    {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera)
        {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    protected void startBackgroundThread()
    {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    protected void stopBackgroundThread()
    {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try
        {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_takepicture)
    void takePicture()
    {
        if (null == cameraDevice)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textture.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            int rotation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, rotation);

            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");
            if (file.exists())
            {
                file.delete();
            }
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
                {
                    try(Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage())
                    {
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException
                {
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try
                    {
                        if (!file.exists())
                        {
                            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            output.write(bytes);
                        }
                    } finally
                    {
                        if (null != output)
                        {
                            output.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result)
                {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_CAPTURED_STENCIL_DATA, new CapturedStencilData(file.getAbsolutePath(), stencilItem));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e)
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session)
                {

                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    protected void createCameraPreview()
    {
        try
        {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textture.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession)
                {
                    if (null == cameraDevice)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    void openCamera()
    {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try
        {
            String cameraId = null;
            if (mCameraLensFacingDirection != null)
            {
                int size = manager.getCameraIdList().length;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    if (mCameraLensFacingDirection == manager.getCameraCharacteristics(manager.getCameraIdList()[i]).get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING))
                    {
                        cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[i];
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                mCameraLensFacingDirection = Objects.requireNonNull(characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING));
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                assert map != null;
                imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            }

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CameraStencilActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            assert cameraId != null;
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    protected void updatePreview()
    {
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try
        {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void closeCamera()
    {
        if (null != cameraDevice)
        {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader)
        {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION)
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textture.isAvailable())
        {
            openCamera();
        } else
        {
            textture.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this image? That's exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza It was given by our designers.